# Define handlers in class and listener in controller?

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs

I have got an extensive controller for my app.
In some cases, the codes differs in a couple of lines.
My idea was, wrote the handlers in the classes and inherit behavior to reduce code. And call this methods in the controller when the event fires.
Its possible?.
Thanks !

Comment: You are talking about just one Controller but redundant code? It is also not clear what you are meaning with `wrote the handlers in the classes and inherit behavior`. Please elaborate your question.

Comment: Yep, it is possible. You can do this in the `initComponent` method. Something like `this.down('#myButton').on('click', this.myButton_click, this);`. But don't forget to call `this.callParent()` first :)

Comment: Alexey, thanks ! i did something similar:
`'AbmUsuarios textfield[action=search]':{
    change: function(field,newVal,oldVal){
        field.up('AbmUsuarios').filterStore(newVal);
    }
}`
Where filterStore() is a method of AbmUsuarios class with AbmUsuarios xtype :)